# SQL selecting content from one table based on another table values as a filter

Tags: sql

I have two tables as follows:

```
USERTABLE

USERID   DATE
1        2022-01-01
2        2022-03-01

STOCKTABLE

USERID    DATE        VALUE    APPROVED
1        2020-12-31    100      Y
1        2022-02-01    50       Y
1        2022-03-01    100      N
2        2022-01-01    10       N
2        2022-03-02    20       N
2        2022-03-05    25       Y
```

I want to select the count of rows for each user after the `DATE` in `USERTABLE` and also the sum of the `VALUES` for `APPROVED` transactions
So my resulting table should look like

```
USERID    COUNT    SUM
1          2       50
2          2        25
```

Please do notice, that I am just taking only one rows for each user, where the  `DATE` in `STOCKTABLE` for each user is greater than the `DATE` in the `USERTABLE` and the `APPROVED` status is `Y`

I tried an inner join
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use conditional aggregation here:

```sql
SELECT u.USERID,
       COUNT(*) AS COUNT,
       SUM(CASE WHEN s.APPROVED = 'Y' THEN s.VALUE ELSE 0 END) AS SUM
FROM USERTABLE u
INNER JOIN STOCKTABLE s
    ON s.USERID = u.USERID AND
       s.DATE > u.DATE
GROUP BY u.USERID
ORDER BY u.USERID;
```